# How to use my base repository methods in custom implementation repository in Spring-Data-JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I followed the reference guide for creating and customizing Repositories and came up with the following:

```
public class MyBasicRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T extends BaseEntity, I extends Serializable>
    extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(
        EntityManager entityManager) {

        return new MyBasicRepositoryFactory<T, I>(entityManager);
    }

    private static class <T extends AlisEntity, I extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public AlisDaoFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityManager);

            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            return new AlisDaoImpl<T, I>((Class<T>) metadata.getDomainType(),
                entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            // The RepositoryMetadata can be safely ignored, it is used by the
            // JpaRepositoryFactory
            // to check for QueryDslJpaRepository's which is out of scope.
            return MyBasicRepository.class;
        }
}





@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyBasicRepository<T extends MyEntity, KEY extends Serializable> extends CrudRepository<T, KEY> {

    void customBaseFoo(T entity);

}

public interface ChildCustomRepository{

    void customChildFoo();
}

public interface ChildRepository extends MyBasicRepository<Child, Integer>, ChildCustomRepository {

    void findByName(String name);
}
```

now on the implementation of `customChildFoo()`, I would like to call `ChildRepository.findByName` or perhaps even `MyBasicRepository.customBaseFoo()`.

These of course are not accessible since the `ChildRepositoryImpl` implements `ChildCustomRepository` and not `ChildRepository`, otherwise I would have to wrote the implementation for the basic CRUD and custom interface as well.

And so I tried to inject `ChildRepository` to the Impl as such:

```
public class ChildRepositoryImpl implements ChildCustomRepository{
    @Resource
    private ChildRepository base;

    @Override
    public void customChildFoo(){
        Child child = base.findByName();
        // do some logic with found child here
        base.customBaseFoo(child);            
    }
```

But it fails due to:
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'childDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:438)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 78 more`

So, how can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I know is to implement interface `ApplicationContextAware` in `ChildRepositoryImpl` class and read the bean like `applicationContext.getBean(<bean name>)`.
I don't want to implement this but this is the only option I know as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You must be very careful in your naming to avoid circular references.

For instance, suppose you want to add custom method to

```
UserDAO
```

To do so, you create a new repository interface called

```
UserDAOCust
```

and then, to be able to use UserDAO repository methods inside your implementation of UserDAOCust, your implementation must be named:

```
UserDAOImpl
```

and inject UserDAO as a member of your fragment.

(By reading the Spring JPA documentation, it seems you must name your implementation as UserDAOCustImpl, but that is actually causing a circular reference)

Complete source (in Kotlin):

```
@Repository
interface UserDAO : CrudRepository<User, Int>, UserDAOCust
{}

interface UserDAOCust
{
    fun findByType(): Optional<List<User>>
}

class UserDAOImpl : UserDAOCust
{
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userDAO: UCUserDAO

    override fun findByType(): Optional<List<User>>
    {
        // use this.userDAO here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to inject parent repository into custom implementation, it's working for me. But I'm not using any  `RepositoryFactoryBean` to customize my repos. Currently using Spring Data JPA 1.3.0, maybe you should try with latest version.