# Pagination in Custom Repository Implementation in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I dont want to fetch the Page object in service layer as ideally, service layer should be decoupled from DAO layer and JPA specific code should not exist in service layer.

Therefore I tried to move the following statement in custom repository layer:
 Page recordsPage = recordRepository.findAll(pageRequest);

I did this by implementing a custom repository class that implements custom repository interface and my actual repository class extends PagingAndSortingRepository, RecordRepositoryCustom.

But the problem is ,I am not able to autowire RecordRepository inside my RepoImpl class. I need reference of RecordRepository to call JPA methods.
I am getting the following error :

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name '    recordRepositoryImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular     reference?

I did research and also make sure the naming convention,  the following link also giving same exception :

[CrudRepository inside my custom repository implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124937/crudrepository-inside-my-custom-repository-implementation)

I also follow same thread on Spring community but no solution is there for the issue :
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/123225-spring-data-calling-default-crud-methods-inside-a-custom-repository-implementation

The following thread is giving one solution is to implement interface ApplicationContextAware in ChildRepositoryImpl class and read the bean like applicationContext.getBean().Is there any other simple approch to resolve it ?

[How to use my base repository methods in custom implementation repository in Spring-Data-JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500796/how-to-use-my-base-repository-methods-in-custom-implementation-repository-in-spr)